# How to configure Node.js v3 bot on directline in a web app?

Tags: node.js, botframework, botconnector

I built my bot using Node.js. It is working fine on web chat and Skype.

Now I want to use direct line to communicate my web app with my bot. I am confused on how I can maintain the URL in my node.js app.

I am trying something like that:

> https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/abc123/how%20are%20you/BotConnector/NsNT2RG8oNA.cwA.Emk.8yB_FdFCy18b4iTcxBscDRxQVAB

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine) you will find a DirectLine Node.js sample that implements a client to talk with a Node.js bot.

Remember that you also need to enable DirectLine in the Bot Developer portal in order to get the DirectLine credentials.